# How to load sample points or coordinates on GPSMAP 62s?

Tags: gps

Does anyone know how to upload 100's of sample points or coordinates from the **[GPSMAP 62s series](http://sites.garmin.com/gpsmap62/info/)** to a computer?

Does anyone also know the steps to create beeps or alarms when we approach these points in field?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Our protocols can take a little getting used to but something I have noticed in your Question is that it contains two questions.  Our Q&A format works best with one question per Question so I recommend that you use the edit button beneath your Question to focus it on one question first and then research/ask the other one separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Basecamp](http://www8.garmin.com/support/mappingsw.jsp). GPSMap 62S is made for use with Basecamp.